# Action bar search widget not detecting query input

Tags: android, android-intent

I am trying to implement a search widget in my app in the action bar, but every time I type a search query and hit enter, nothing happens. I think it has something to do with my AndroidManifest file, but I have tried many things and can't figure it out. This query gets its results from an api. I have been trying to get this to work for about 6 hours now. Here is my code as of now(I've tried many different things):

**searchable.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<searchable xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:label="@string/app_name"
  android:hint="@string/search_hint" >
</searchable>
```

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SYNC_SETTINGS" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

    <meta-data android:name="android.app.default_searchable"
        android:value=".SearchAppsActivity" />

    <activity
        android:name="com.android.devon.BrowseAppsActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_browse_apps" >

    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".SearchAppsActivity" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEARCH" />
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter >
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
        </intent-filter>

        <meta-data android:name="android.app.searchable"
            android:resource="@xml/searchable"/>
    </activity>
</application>
```

**SearchAppsActivity**

```
public class SearchAppsActivity extends ListActivity
{
private AppFrenzy restClient;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_browse_apps);
    handleIntent(getIntent());

}

public void onNewIntent(Intent intent)
{
    setIntent(intent);
    handleIntent(intent);
}

public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id)
{

}

private void handleIntent(Intent intent)
{
    if(Intent.ACTION_SEARCH.equals(intent.getAction()))
    {
        String query = intent.getStringExtra(SearchManager.QUERY);
        doSearch(query);
    }

}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the options menu from XML
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.browse_apps, menu);

    // Get the SearchView and set the searchable configuration
    SearchManager searchManager = (SearchManager) getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);
    SearchView searchView = (SearchView) menu.findItem(R.id.action_search).getActionView();
    // Assumes current activity is the searchable activity
    searchView.setSearchableInfo(searchManager.getSearchableInfo(getComponentName()));
    searchView.setIconifiedByDefault(false); // Do not iconify the widget; expand it by default

    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu( menu );

}

private void doSearch(String queryStr)
{
    restClient = AppService.getService();

    restClient.searchApps(queryStr, new Callback<List<App>>() {
        @Override
        public void success(List<App> apps, Response response) {
            setListAdapter(new AppListAdapter(SearchAppsActivity.this, apps));

            Log.v("test", "search successful");
            Log.v("test", "search results:" + apps.toString() );
        }

        @Override
        public void failure(RetrofitError retrofitError) {
            Log.v("test", "failure");
        }
    });
}
}
```

Any thoughts as to why my search isn't being submitted?

Answer (score 0):

You can use SearchView.OnQueryTextListener for your problem .

example,

**in main.xml**

```
             <item
    android:id="@+id/action_websearch"
    android:actionViewClass="android.widget.SearchView"
    android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_search"
    android:showAsAction="always"
    android:title="@string/search_title"/>
```

**in onCreateOptionsMenu()**

```
        @Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
     SearchView  searchView = (SearchView) menu.findItem(R.id.action_websearch)
            .getActionView();
    // searchView.setQueryHint("Search Patient name");
    searchView.setQueryHint(Html.fromHtml("<font color = #ffffff>"
            + getResources().getString(R.string.hint) + "</font>"));
    if (null != searchView) {
        searchView.setSearchableInfo(searchManager
                .getSearchableInfo(getComponentName()));

        searchView.setIconifiedByDefault(true);

    }
         SearchView.OnQueryTextListener queryTextListener = new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {


        public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
            // this is your adapter that will be filtered

       }     //this method will call while press (click) search button.
              public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {


                 // add searching stuff here 

            }
      }
     return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);

  }
```

**note:**

```
Don't need searchable.xml and any permission on androidmanifest.xml.
```